# I want to cancel page submit ,on cancel action of confirm using C# in asp.net4.0

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to stop page submit on cancel action of confirm .

What I want to achive is , I have a form with server validation, if user submit the form without entering any fields, it should validate the form and no confirm window should open.
But now if user have filled all the fields and go on submit the form, It should confirm the page submission (Are you sure you want to create user.),
So on clicking yes it should submit the page .
But on cancel it should cancel the page submission.

My only problem is with the cancel as it is still submitting the form.

my code in javascript is as follows:

```
function ConfirmSubmit() {
    Page_ClientValidate(); 
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return ConfirmSubmit()" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
```

I have server code on btnSave_Click.

Please help me , I have tried many things but could not sucesseed

Many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this on button Client event

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm?');"
```

try this:

```
  function ConfirmSubmit(){
Page_ClientValidate(); 
if(Page_IsValid) {

return confirm('Confirm?');
 }
}


<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return ConfirmSubmit()" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Akhtar, But I have already tried this solution, My problem is with the validation controls, If I use the code mentioned by you, validation controls also get fired along with the confirm window. I dont want confirm window if form is not validated,if my form is validated then on OK action of confirm should submit the form and cancel action should not submit the form . main concern is the cancel action of the confirm window as it is also submiting the form...... Hope you got my point

Comment: This code is working fine for me , I just want to handle the cancel action of the confirm.I dont want form submit or postback on cancel action.Right now both OK and Cancel are doing same stuff...submitting the form

Comment: Well I was doing it right , it all happened because I was simply calling function javascript:ConfirmSubmit() but not returning it.